# Error when trying to stack two ragged tensors

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, ragged-tensors

I'm getting an odd error when trying to use `tf.ragged.stack`. I'm trying to stack two tensors t1, t2, however they have different rank. t2 is 1 rank less than t1. Therefore I used `tf.expand_dims` to increase the rank of t2 so the ranks match. However when I go to stack them I get an error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
t1 = tf.ones([2,10,10], tf.int32)
t2 = tf.ragged.constant([
                         [0,1,2,3,4,5],
                         [0,1,2,3,4]
])
t2 = tf.expand_dims(t2, -1)
tf.ragged.stack([t1, t2])
```

The error I get is

> InvalidArgumentError: ConcatOp : Dimensions of inputs should match: shape[0] = [20,10] vs. shape[1] = [11,1] [Op:ConcatV2] name: concat

However when I create an equivalent tensor from scratch I don't get the error.

```
t2_new = tf.ragged.constant([
                         [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]],
                         [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]

tf.ragged.stack([t1, t2_new]) # no error
```

The difference between t2 and t2 new is that tensorflow thinks their shapes are different even though they actually represent the same tensor

```
print(t2.shape) # == (2,None,1)
print(t2_new.shape) # == (2, None, None)
print(tf.math.reduce_all(t2 == t2_new)) # == True i.e actually the same tensor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually not that trivial, as `tf.expand_dims` adds a new dimension, but not a ***ragged*** dimension, which is necessary to stack both tensors afterwards. Generally, it is possible but a bit more complicated than just adding a new dimension. I would recommend using [tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor?version=nightly#from_value_rowids) with [tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/RaggedTensor?version=nightly#from_row_splits):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

t1 = tf.ones([2,10,10], tf.int32)
t2 = tf.ragged.constant([[0,1,2,3,4,5],
                         [0,1,2,3,4]])

t2_new = tf.ragged.constant([
                         [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]],
                         [[0],[1],[2],[3],[4]]])

flattened_ragged_tensor = t2.flat_values
rows = tf.cast(t2.bounding_shape()[0], dtype=tf.int32)
t2 = tf.RaggedTensor.from_value_rowids(
    values=tf.RaggedTensor.from_row_splits(
        values=flattened_ragged_tensor,
        row_splits=tf.range(tf.shape(flattened_ragged_tensor)[0] + 1)),
    value_rowids=tf.concat([tf.tile([i], [t2[i].shape[0]]) for i in tf.range(rows)], axis=0),
    nrows=rows)

print(t2.shape)
print(t2_new.shape)

print(tf.ragged.stack([t1, t2]))
print(tf.ragged.stack([t1, t2_new]))
```

```
(2, None, None)
(2, None, None)
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]]]>
<tf.RaggedTensor [[[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]]], [[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5]], [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4]]]]>
```

Comment: Thanks (again) for the answer! It seems then that `tf.ragged.stack` is not fully implemented for Rank >= 2 then? I don't feel like your answer should be necessary and it is not specified as necessary in the documentation [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/ragged/stack)