# Combining Tensors in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor, ragged-tensors

I would like to combine a number of ragged tensors into a single tensors so that I can quickly and conviently access my data. But I'm not sure that I've formatted the combined tensor correctly as I'm new to tensors and using tensorflow.

Specifically I have 3 ragged tensors of dimension (5, None) given by

```
theta1 = [10, 9, 8, 7]
phi1 = [20, 19, 18, 17]
x1 = [30, 29, 28, 27]
y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
z1 = [0.01]
tensor1 = tf.ragged.constant([theta1,
                              phi1,
                              x1,
                              y1,
                              z1])

theta2 = [100, 150]
phi2 = [200, 250]
x2 = [300, 350]
y2 = [10, 15]
z2 = [0.1]
tensor2 = tf.ragged.constant([theta2,
                              phi2,
                              x2,
                              y2,
                              z2])

theta3 = [50, 70, 80]
phi3 = [100, 120, 130]
x3 = [150, 170, 180]
y3 = [5, 5, 5]
z3 = [0.001]
tensor3 = tf.ragged.constant([theta3,
                              phi3,
                              x3,
                              y3,
                              z3])
```

I then combine them into a new tensor and using the following

```
combined_tensor = tf.stack([tensor1, tensor2, tensor3], axis=0)`
```

My understanding is that this should create a (3,5,None) tensor since tf.stack combines the tensors in a new axis. This gives 3 in the first position and then the original dimensions of my tensors in the following positions (5, None).

However when I run `print("Shape of tensor:", rank_3_ragged_tensor.shape)` it returns `(3, None, None)`.

Have I done something wrong when combining my tensors or am I not understanding how they work correctly?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70640696/8658598) answer your question?